# How does one get Properties using Reflection, while ignoring the inherited properties?

Tags: c#, reflection

To get the properties is not big deal, but I don´t want to get the properties inherited from another class. The `bindingFlags` option doesn´t have any option of this kind.

Is that possible ?

cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) with your [Type.GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) call in order to specify to just get the properties from the specified type.

For example, to get all non-static properties on a type without looking up it's hierarchy, you could do:

```
var properties = theType.GetProperties(
                          BindingFlags.Public | 
                          BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                          BindingFlags.Instance | 
                          BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Comment: Thanks Reed, worked fine, I was trying without the 'Public' BindingFlags, just the 'Instance' one will return 0 properties... school boy error. cheers !